# netExtender vpn 6.0 works momentarily then remote hosts timeout

Tags: vpn

My company uses netExtender 6.0. I successfully installed it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which included manually symlinking an libssl and libcrypto libraries, as well as disabling avahi daemon.

Now, I can log into the VPN successfully. Once logged in, I can ping a host and/or load a web page on the corporate network - but only for a few seconds.  Then all pings stop working / web pages time out.

What is going on - how can I get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: Upgrade to Net Extender v7.